# Toggle Div Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have some divs on my page that when a link is clicked they need to toggle (show/hide)

JS

```
var state = 'none';

function showhide(layer_ref) {
//alert(eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display") == "none")

if (document.all) { //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta)
if(eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display") == "none"){
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = 'block'");
}else{
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = 'none'");
}

}
if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below
if(document.layers[layer_ref].display == none){
document.layers[layer_ref].display = "block";
}else{
document.layers[layer_ref].display = "none";
}
}
if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) {
if(document.getElementById(layer_ref).style.display == "none"){
document.getElementById(layer_ref).style.display = "block";
}else{
document.getElementById(layer_ref).style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

HTML

```
     <div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
       <span class="itp-title"><a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1');">title</a></span>
        <div id="div1" style="display: none;">divcont</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
       <span class="itp-title"><a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1');">title</a></span>
        <div id="div2" style="display: none;">divcont</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
       <span class="itp-title"><a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1');">title</a></span>
        <div id="div3" style="display: none;">divcont</div>
     </div>
```

my problem is that no matter what link i click it only toggles the first div? Cany anybody see where im going wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Unless you're writing this code for some EXTREMELY specific application environment, there's no reason to support anything before IE 6 (IE4, IE5, netscape etc). Most applications don't even support IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue is trying to write non-trivial crossbrowser JavaScript. This would be much, **much** simpler if you used something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

That said, your issue is that your `onClick` handlers are all pointing to the same `id`.

```
onclick="showhide('div1');"
```

Change these to the relevant div id's and you should be fine.

If you used something like jQuery, this function would be irrelevant though and you could just do something like:

```
onclick="$('#div1').toggle()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have showhide(`div1`) for each of the showhide events .. that should read div2 and div3

EDIT:
also, another show/hide may be this ...

```
function showhide(elementid){
obj=document.getElementById(elementid);
obj.style.display=(obj.style.display=='none')?(''):('none');    
}//both
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `"showhide('div1');"` on every onclick event. Try changing them to `"showhide('div1');"`, `"showhide('div2');"`, and `"showhide('div3');"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're always calling `showhide('div1')`. On every div's onclick

Answer (score 0):

If you have `jQuery`:

```
function showhide(element) {
    $(element).toggle();
}
```

would be much simpler of course. Is `jQuery` an option?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we do it in 2011 ;)

```
$('.itp-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rcr38/

Learn this: [http://jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call showHide() with each div id.
here is a live example http://toggle-example.qip.li/edit/